# Display parent page URL for child page

Tags: permalinks

I have this code that is working but is giving me the wrong link

gives me this link `example.com/index.php/sample-page/`

but I need this link `example.com/sample-page/`

```
 <?php global $post;
  if ( $post->post_parent ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" >
    <?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?>
    </a> <Br><?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$post->post_parent` returns 0 when there's no parent associated. You need to check if the value is greater than 0.

```
<?php global $post;
  if ( $post->post_parent > 0 ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" >
    <?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?>
    </a> <Br><?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, check your permalink settings URL base.

Comment: Omg,  the problem was in my permanent settings thank you so much.  never had this ( index.php ) by default in permanent links settings before